# Elegant way to convert units Centimeters (Cm) to Meters (m) and Vice Versa

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

I am looking forward a way to develop an elegant way to Convert Cm to Meter and vice versa without using IF conditions or Select Case, only working on Boolean type.
Thes "tmp" variable manipulation will be in a elegant way that will NOT change when the value is already in Meters.

```
MyVariable
tmp= Not(MyVariable>100)
tmp= (MyVariable*tmp)/100 '(Converting to meters in case the Value is in Cm)
```

Comment: What is so bad about `if`?

Comment: `tmp = MyVariable if MyVariable <= 100 else MyVariable / 100`

Comment: The ideia is NOT using the IF or Select Case.

Comment: Besides the ambiguous use of the `tmp`variable with differring  type assignments (first boolean, then numeric) it's unclear how one can distinguish meters from centimeters only by ist numeric value.   Following your logic you *exclude* numbers **greater 100** completely from calculation as `tmp` will be `False` thus resulting in a *zero* multiplication and a result of `0` (even if not so its unclear how you expect valid meter inputs). Furthermore the `tmp` variable set to `True` for your cm indications (i.e. <=100) has a value of `-1` thus leading in a possibly unwanted *negative* result :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is not a matter of bad or good. It is finding/developing different ways to reach the result. Sometimes elegantly sometimes optimized.

```
Sub ToggleTrueOrFalseSlower()
 Dim bYesNo As Boolean

 If bYesNo = False Then
  bYesNo = True
 Else
  bYesNo = False
 End If
End Sub

Sub ToggleTrueOrFalseFaster()
 Dim bYesNo As Boolean
 bYesNo = Not bYesNo
End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does this answer the (very broad) question?

Answer (score -1):

Guys I guess I could solve using this. Only the Number divided by Zero is the problem right now.

```
tmp=(10)^(2*(MyVariable>100))
```

What do you think guys? See a sample code:

```
Function BMI(W As Double, H As Double)
  Dim tmp As Double
  tmp = (W * H) > 0
  tmp = tmp * ((10) ^ (2 * (H > 100)) * H)
  BMI = Round(W / (tmp ^ 2), 1)
End Function
```